# iCloud Drive takes forever to load

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, icloud

I am trying to open open iCloud Drive from my browser and it is stuck at the loading stage:

[image]

Do you have any idea about how I can resolve this problem? I am using Google Chrome and my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser or a different machine? What browser and OS are you currently using? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited my question. I have not tried opening iCloud on a different browser than Chrome.

Comment: You might need to clear cookies for that site. Try https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB but make sure to look under the "Delete specific cookies" section rather than deleting *all* cookies.

Comment: @Mokubai 

_You might need to clear cookies for that site._ Which site are you referring to?

Comment: The iCloud site, typically the URL in the address bar after the "https://" and before the next "/". Presumably it should be "icloud" or icloud.apple.com or something similar.

Comment: @Mokubai I cleared the cookies and tried to open the iCloud Drive on Chrome and the outcome is still the same: iCloud is not moving past the loading page. I tried to sign in with Microsoft Edge and iCloud continued to be stuck at the loading stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118034/discussion-between-a-sid-and-mokubai).

Comment: This is a web app and is off-topic here. Try asking it [webapps.se].